# Asynchronous declaration with delegate Func<T,T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I try to declare this:

```
public static async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(Func<T,T> read)
{
    return await Task.Run(read);
}
```

and I have an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<T, T>' to 'System.Action'

I can't fix it.
I try this and have an error too: *'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context*.

```
public static async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(Func<T,T> read)
{
    return await Task.Run(read(T));
}
```

Comment: You can't get the value you need to put into the read call you don't have it here. Either also put that thing that should be put into the read call also as another parameter into the ReadAsync signature or change the signature to just take a Func<T>  and handle the input parameter inside the calling func.

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the main purpose of this `ReadAsync` method? What exactly do you want to achieve with that? It does feel like this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Could you include in the question an example of how you intend to use the `ReadAsync` method?

Comment: public async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer)
        {
            return await SerialPortLb.ReadAsync((byte[] b,int) =>
            {
                return _port.Read(b, 0, b.Length);                
            });
        }

Comment: i want to write a task return int value and the func<byte[],int> i have a problem with my lambda

Comment: If you want, you can edit the question by clicking the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75948218/edit) button under the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Func<T,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-7.0) is a delegate which represents a function accepting single parameter of type `T` and returning `TResult`, so `Func<T, T>` is a function that accepts single parameter and returns value of the same type, `Func<int, int> myFunc = i => i + 1;` can be a good example.

[`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-8.0) has several overloads none of them has delegate accepting parameters, it either [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-7.0) delegate (accepts no params and returns nothing) or `Func<TResult>` (or `Func<Task<TResult>>` to handle async functions, but again - no parameters, only return value). Also usually you will want to read a value from "another type". So your have the following options:

1. Provide parameterless delegate (though in this concrete case does not make much sense):

   ```cs
   static Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(Func<T> read) => Task.Run(read);
   ```

   With usage like `ReadAsync(() => myValueHolder.GetValue())`
2. Use 2 generic parameters and provide instance to the first one (also can be make extension method):

   ```
   static Task<TResult> ReadAsync<T, TResult>(T valueHolder, Func<T, TResult> read) 
        => Task.Run(() => read(valueHolder));
   ```
3. If your `ReadAsync` method has the valueHolder available - remove the first parameter, though usage will require to pass both generic parameters:

   ```
   static async Task<TResult> ReadAsync<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> read)
   {
       T valueHolder = ...;
       return await Task.Run(() => read(valueHolder));
   }
   ```

   And usage `ReadAsync<SomeType, SomeResult>(t => t.GetValue())`

Notes:

- In some cases `async-await` can be skipped - read more about [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).
- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).